# AngularJS - create custom converter for a view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, converters

I use AngularJS 1.5 and have an object, let's say:

```
myObject = {
  ts: 1497971053529, //time in ms
  field: { a: b } //some object
}
```

I want user to observe and **edit** `myObject`'s fields, but I want to show `ts` as a date (day, `yyyy.mm.dd`), and `field` should be in json. Something like that:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myObject.ts"
    wtf-to-converter="longToDate" wtf-from-converter="dateToLong">
<input type="text" ng-model="myObject.field"
    wtf-to-converter="objectToJson" wtf-from-converter="jsonToObject">
```

result:

```
2017.06.20
{"a":"b"}
```

So how to implement these converters? If I need only to observe these values I could use AngularJS pipes: `{{myObject.field | json }}`, but I need to edit it too.

That might be a dumb question, but I'm backend developer and not yet accustomed to frontend features. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like the example below:
It's a directive that converts text to date and date to text using formatters (model -> user) and parsers (user -> model).

```
(function (angular) {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("YourModule").directive("msDate", msDate);

    function msDate() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: "ngModel",
            link: link
        };

        function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            // From the user to the model
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                return new Date(value).getTime();
            });
            // From the model to the user
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                return new Date(value);
            });
        }
    }
}(angular));
```

It's not a full solution for your problem, but you'll get the idea;

The usage is something like:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="yourModel" ms-date>
```